# Check Strict Superset[Hackerrank problem]

Tags: python, set

So I've been solving hackerrank problems, and I have encountered a pretty strange problem that's been bugging me for hours now.
Kindly refer to the problem question here:
[Strict Superset Hackerrank Problem](https://codeworld19.blogspot.com/2020/08/check-strict-superset-in-python-hacker.html)

Below is my code for this:

```
import sys
s = set(map(int, input().split()))
inp = int(input())
res = True 

while(inp):
    a = set(map(int, input().split()))
    if len(s) < len(a):
        res = False
        print(res)
        sys.exit()
    if len(s) > len(a):
        res = s.issuperset(a)
    
    inp -= 1
print(res)
```

When I typed this on hackerrank, it works for all the cases except for the last test case.
Upon observation, I came to a conclusion that my code **"might not"** work for cases where the last comparison returns True, regardless of the comparisons before.
I tried updating my code(The one I posted is the updated one), by trying to exit as soon as I find the first instance of False, **but to no avail.**
[Here is the Link for the Input, for the last Test case that I've been facing a problem with](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A_HTzyktO1bRkH2FRXaNS2Vfa3Bd_WzN/view?usp=sharing)

So Basically, this is supposed to exit on the first instance of False, but it seems to be not.
Kindly help me out. Many thanks!

Comment: You have an unhandled edge case in here where the lengths of the two sets could be equal. This is likely where your issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two gaps in this program: first, there is a potential unhandled edge case where the two sets could be equal length. This can be adjusted in your first conditional by making it `<=` instead of just `<`.

Additionally, when you set `res = s.issuperset(a)`, you *also* need to break when `res` is False, because in the next iteration, the result may be overridden to `True` again, which you don't want.

```
s = set(map(int, input().split()))
inp = int(input())
res = True 

while(inp):
    a = set(map(int, input().split()))
    if len(s) <= len(a):
        res = False
        print(res)
        sys.exit()
    if len(s) > len(a):
        res = s.issuperset(a)
        if not res:
            break
    
    inp -= 1
print(res)
```

---

On a totally unrelated note, I couldn't help myself, and minified the solution to this problem as much as I reasonably could. This is also a valid solution to the challenge:

```
superset = set(map(int, input().split()))
print(all(map(
    lambda subset: len(superset) > len(subset) and superset.issuperset(subset), 
    [set(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(int(input()))]
)))
```

Comment: Thank you SO much for this answer! While I could definitely not understand your simplified answer, I more than understood where I went wrong with the first one!  
Hoping to be as cool as you someday :)

Comment: @NKRao, There are only two concepts I really used here that I can see that you might not understand on the "minified" answer. Those are list comprehension and lambdas. I highly recommend looking them up if you have a chance, and see if you can't pick apart what exactly my code is doing, just to learn a bit more about Python.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this was a bit shorter, and sounds a bit more easier to read. If you define A being a strict superset of B, you'd have the following property:

The subtraction B-A will be a non-empty, and the A-B would be empty. Written in python, you have this:

````py
A = set(input().split())
n = int(input())
N = [set(input().split()) for _ in range(n)]

print(all([(not s-A and A-s) for s in N]))```

An even better better implementation would be using the strictly less than comparison which [can be used to check for super sets too][1]

updating the last line, we have:

```python
print(all([s<A for s in N]))
````